# show indexOfObject in UILabel

Tags: uilabel, type-conversion

I am trying to show the number of objects in an `NSArray` in a `UILabel` as part of a `UITabelViewCell`:

```
UILabel *numberLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
numberLabel.numberOfLines = [self.inputValues indexOfObject:inputValue];
NSLog(@"rownumber is: %d", numberLabel.numberOfLines);
```

The `NSLog`gives me the right number, but the label shows just the default title value. What am I missing here? No errors are thrown.

Comment: Well, *what* should it show? You don't set its text anywhere... Also any particular reason you set the height (in lines) of the label to the index of the `inputValue`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the label's `text` property.  Example:

```
NSUInteger index = [self.inputValues indexOfObject:inputValue];
numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %lu", (unsigned long)index];
```

However, it seems likely that you could just use the `row` from the cell's index path, like this:

```
numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %ld", (long)indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks, the second approach works fine for me. I tried this before but missed the `(long)` portion.

Comment: On iOS, `NSUInteger` is `unsigned int` and `NSInteger` is `int`, so you could use `%u`/`%d` and omit the cast.  However, on OS X, `NSUInteger` is `unsigned long` and `NSInteger` is `long`.  I am in the habit of casting so that I can use the same code on either iOS or OS X.

Comment: Thank you! I still need to learn a lot more before I can start with having habits...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that instead you want:

```
UILabel *numberLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.inputValues indexOfObject:inputValue]];
NSLog(@"rownumber is: %d", numberLabel.numberOfLines);
```

Comment: @H2CO3 With the limited info I have, I'm assuming the OP confused `text` with `numberOfLines` - look at the `NSLog`. Really, though, without further clarification from the OP, I'm guessing. Anyway, when was the last time *you* used `numberOfLines` in a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: It was when I've written my [file downloader class](https://github.com/H2CO3/HCDownload/blob/master/HCDownloadCell.m#l30).

Comment: @H2CO3 This is true - it's simply not something (I, at least) do every day.

Comment: @JFS 'Original Poster'. (you)

Comment: @H2CO3 (Almost) everyone here knows how to read and write - but the Apple docs aren't exactly a great read - they tend to be dry, and it's just easier to read something else.